# I want to add a babel plugin inside create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to add the following babel configuration in `react-scripts` I don't want to eject from cra I want to keep using it without ejecting. I see there is a way to fork the repo and add your custom configuration. But I want to know where exactly I can paste this.

```
// .babelrc or babel-loader option
{
  "plugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }] // `style: true` for less
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The entire point of the non-ejected version of a cra app is that it is an "ensured" setup. You're essentially looking to take responsibility and deviate from that setup.

Answer (score 2):

There is, in theory, [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra), which lets you do things like override Babel plugins.

[Here is a list of things you can do](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md).

It doesn't appear to be maintained at time of writing, and for me didn't seem usable if your project is modules-based (ie `import`) as opposed to `require`.

CRA itself [recommends forking their scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting) as an alternative to ejecting, which is a pretty bold statement.

Answer (score -3):

If you wish to override a property of one of the config files of React, you can just create that config file in your project's main directory and just set that single property, this will override that property in React's configuration. For babel you can just add it as a property in package.json like so:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [ ... ],
    "plugins": [ ... ],
  }
```

If you run npm run-script eject you are going to get a copy of all the config that ReactJS uses for your project in the main directory of your project/config, from there you can edit whatever you like, keep version tracking of your changes and not mess with the react repository.

If you insist on forking it you can fork the main create-react-app repository from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), which contains the react-scripts [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts)

Comment: "For babel you can just add it as a property in package.json like so: [...]" Where did you read that? I've tried adding a babel plugin to package.json (under "babel"->"plugins"), and it's just ignored.